# Check common elements of two-dimensional arrays of integers, considering the positions they are on

Tags: c#

at the beginning I want to mention that I am a beginner in programming. So, I want to write a program that checks the similarity of two-dimensional arrays of integers. The similarity is to be determined by the amount of numbers that are in the same positions in both tables. The user gives the number of columns in the table and the elements themselves, number of rows is the same all the time.The similarity result is displayed as a percentage and the similarity itself should be calculated taking into account the number of elements of the larger array. My problem is: When the two arrays are the same size, the program throws the exception and it doesn't check all the numbers in the column.(I wrote before program for one dimensional array and it works perfectly) So far I have managed to write something like this:

[This is what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilKre.png) In the picture, the similarity between the arrays is 20%

```
        {

            Console.WriteLine("How extensive is the first table supposed to be?");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int z = 2;
            int[,] tab1 = new int[2, n];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers into the first array:");
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    tab1[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            int rowLength = tab1.GetLength(0);
            int colLength = tab1.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", tab1[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("How extensive is the second table supposed to be?");
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int b = 2;
            int[,] tab2 = new int[2, m];


            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers into the second array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    tab2[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
           Console.WriteLine("\n");
            int Len4gth = tab2.GetLength(0);
            int Len2gth = tab2.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < Len4gth; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Len2gth; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", tab2[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }


            double similarity= 0;

            if (tab1.GetLength(1) > tab2.GetLength(1))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tab2.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
                    {
                        if (tab1[i, j] == tab2[i, j])
                        {
                            similarity+= 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (tab1.GetLength(1) < tab2.GetLength(1))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tab1.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
                    {
                        if (tab2[i, j] == tab1[i, j])
                        {
                            similarity+= 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (tab1.GetLength(1) == tab2.GetLength(1))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tab1.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
                    {
                        if (tab1[i, j] == tab2[i, j])
                        {
                            similarity+= 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            if (tab1.Length < tab2.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The similarity of the arrays is:   " + (similarity/ tab2.Length) * 100 + "%");
            }

            if (tab1.Length > tab2.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The similarity of the arrays is:  " + (similarity/ tab1.Length) * 100 + "%");

            }

            if (tab1.Length == tab2.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The similarity of the arrays is:  " + (similarity/ tab2.Length) * 100 + "%");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compare each element of the first array with the elements of the second array.

use this code :

```
 //get first array items
            Console.WriteLine("How extensive is the first table supposed to be?");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] tab1 = new int[2, n];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers into the first array:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    tab1[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            //write first array items
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", tab1[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //get second array items
            Console.WriteLine("How extensive is the second table supposed to be?");
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] tab2 = new int[2, m];


            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers into the second array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    tab2[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            //write second array items
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", tab2[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //find similarity items
            double similarity = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    int firstValue = tab1[i, j];

                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < m; d++)
                        {
                            if (firstValue == tab2[k, d])
                            {
                                similarity += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            double percentage = n > m ? ((similarity / tab1.Length) * 100) : ((similarity / tab2.Length) * 100);
            Console.WriteLine("The similarity of the arrays is:  " + percentage + "%");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

this code work without error and It does not matter which array is larger.

If you want similar elements like this example [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilKre.png), use this code snippet to find similar elements

```
//find similarity items
double similarity = 0;
int z = n > m ? m : n;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
    {
       if (tab1[i, j] == tab2[i, j])
       {
          similarity += 1;
       }
    }
}


double percentage = n > m ? ((similarity / tab1.Length) * 100) : ((similarity / tab2.Length) * 100);
Console.WriteLine("The similarity of the arrays is:  " + percentage + "%");
Console.ReadKey();
```